# Unable to git clone from one folder to another in windows

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I have a created a bare repository in C drive and I'm trying to clone the same in D drive by issuing the below command (in windows machine)

```
git clone Username@Ip_address_of_my_machine:C:/path_to_the_git_repo
```

but I'm unable clone it as it comes up with the error

```
"Cloning into 'git_repos'...
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.5 port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote    repository.
 Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists."
```

I have installed CopSSH and set up `id_rsa.pub` keys and authorized key.
as mentioned in on [github](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Setting-up-a-Git-server-on-Windows-using-Git-for-Windows-and-CopSSH).

Is this problem is because of the dynamic IP address of my PC which is getting from the service provider? or what else is missing here?

I have tried the same in my office PC with same settings and installation, it works well with above git clone command, The difference is office PC has static IP but @home it is dynamic IP

Comment: For local copies you don't need SSH. Try `git clone C:/path_to_the_git_repo`.

Comment: `ssh -vvv Username@192.168.0.5` will also fail. Check the logs from the ssh server. Do you have firewall on your machine? `ssh -vvv Username@127.0.0.1` works?

Comment: @Jakuje thank u for the reply, will check and let you know

Answer (score 2):

Skip the ssh part as this is on the same machine.  So from where you want the project to be in the D drive:

```
git clone C:/path_to_the_git_repo
```

Comment: Patrick ,thank you for the answer, but could you also please tell me how to do it with ssh as I did the in my office pc with copssh and all it works well , it does cloning with       git clone Username@Ip_address_of_my_machine:C:/path_to_the_git_repo... But in office pc the IP address is static, but @ my home it is dynamic can this be the reason?